# What is the difference between univariate and multivariate time series?

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, definition, differences

I have the following time series data:

```
index              Time        value_1  value_2  value_3
 0        2016-04-01 06:00:10     1       5         2
 1        2016-04-01 06:00:20     2       9         8
 2        2016-04-01 06:00:30     3       5         1
 3        2016-04-01 06:00:40     4       4         4
 4        2016-04-01 06:00:50     3       4         5
 6        2016-04-01 06:01:00     4       3         2
```

Is this a univariate or a multivariate time series? What is the difference between univariate and multivariate time series?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Univariate time series:** Only one variable is varying over time. For example, data collected from a sensor measuring the temperature of a room every second. Therefore, each second, you will only have a one-dimensional value, which is the temperature.

**Multivariate time series:** Multiple variables are varying over time. For example, a tri-axial accelerometer. There are three accelerations, one for each axis (x,y,z) and they vary simultaneously over time.

Considering the data you showed in the question, you are dealing with a multivariate time series, where `value_1`, `value_2` and`value_3` are three variables changing simultaneously over time.